# QoS on HP Procurve 2520 and 3800 switches

Tags: qos, cos, hp, dscp, hp-procurve

Do Procurve switches remark cos/dscp values between switches (trust boundaries) as Cisco switches do?

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to "mls qos trust (cos/dscp)" in the HP realm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If my memory serves, the older Procurve switches used to accept and forward any CoS/DSCP markings they received.  You couldn't modify them unless you were on a 5400xl or better switch.

It looks like the 2520 and the 3800 allow you to modify whether or not you're using CoS or DiffServ TOS for classification.  The top level command you want is *qos type-of-service*.  The rest of the commands should be contained under that.  If they aren't available, you may not be able to modify the QoS settings on that specific platform.

Answer (score 5):

The HP ProCurve switches can have 802.1p CoS Priorities or DSCP Policies set, honored, changed or honored with new priority.

- By default, Quality of Service is ENABLED and operates based on
  802.1p settings in the packet.
- Classification is configured primarily on a global basis; but can be configured by VLAN and port.
- Marking is configured primarily on a global basis.
- Some configuration options can be set globally and some also set by VLAN or port.
- Queue Scheduling is configured per port.

For the ProCurve range, its always worth looking through one particular manual which is the "[Advanced Traffic Management Guide](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c03018186/c03018186.pdf)" For the 3800 Series (which by the way, shares the same firmware as the 3500/5400/6200/6600/8200 series) it has 80-odd pages on configuring or setting up Quality of Service.

Lastly, its always worth looking through "[HP Networking and Cisco CLI reference Guide](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/docs/interoperability/Cisco/HP-Networking-and-Cisco-CLI-Reference-Guide_June_10_WW_Eng_ltr.pdf)"; this takes common Cisco configuration examples, and provides a HP ProCurve or HP Comware equivalant